# Probability integral

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

How do I calculate (or approximate) the integral:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)(\frac{b}{a})^a} \int_0^{\infty} (\frac{c}{c+x})^cx^{a-1}e^{-\frac{a}{b}x} dx$$

It is the probability of $P(X = 0)$ if $X|Y \sim \text{NegativeBinomial}(\text{size} = c, \text{mean} = Y)$ and $Y \sim \text{Gamma}(\text{shape} = a, \text{scale} = \frac{b}{a})$. Notice that I use the size-mean parameterisation of the negative binomial distribution.